# Disappearance of the table title/caption, when using colortbl

Tags: tables, color, captions, templates, colortbl

I'm formatting a manuscript according to the PNAS style, as prescribed in http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/LaTex.xhtml

When I color my table using the package `colortbl`, the title/caption disappears (the content of the table is just fine). From my testing, it seems the only way to get the title back is to remove `colortbl` package and `\cellcolor` from the table. I can speculate that there must be a conflict between `pnastwo` document class and `colortbl`, but I have no idea how to get around this problem.
Has anyone experienced this? I appreciate your suggestions!

FYI, I use MacOS X 10.6.8 and TeXShop 2.47

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage{colortbl,xr}

\begin{document}
\begin{article}
\end{article}

\clearpage
\begin{table}
\caption{TITLE}\label{LAB}
\begin{tabular}{ p{4.5cm} p{.8cm} | p{1.2cm}}
Name 1 & first & second \\ \hline\hline
value1 & \cellcolor[gray]{0.7}0.004 & 0.034 \\ 
value2 & 7721 & \cellcolor[gray]{0.7}0.14 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thanks for providing a complete MWE! If you load the `caption` package, the problem seems to be fixed :) Given that I can't explain it, I won't post it as an answer- I'm sure a guru will be along soon, perhaps Axel (`caption` expert) will see this :)

Comment: I have to go to work earlier than usual today so unfortunately I have no time to examine this until tomorrow. But as opposite to the usual `\caption` code provided by the document classes the `caption` package's code do a `\normalcolor` (unless a color is set), and I assume this fixes the caption color issue here.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The problem is actually unrelated to `colortbl`. You see the same thing if you just use `array`.  Classes should not really be incompatible with `array` which is part of the core LaTeX distribution, however this one is. So you need to re-do some of its changes after loading `array`.

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage{colortbl,xr}

\makeatletter
\def\tabular{\global\setbox\tablewide\hbox\bgroup
\let\@halignto\@empty\@tabular}


\def\endtabular{\crcr\egroup\egroup $\egroup\egroup
\centerline{\vbox{\hsize\wd\tablewide 
\currtabcaption\vskip1pt
}}
\dimen0=\wd\tablewide
\centerline{\hbox{\unhbox\tablewide}}
\centerline{\vtop{\hsize=\dimen0 \tablenotes}}
\global\let\currtabcaption\relax}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{article}
\end{article}

\clearpage
\begin{table}
\caption{TITLE}\label{LAB}
\begin{tabular}{ p{4.5cm} p{.8cm} | p{1.2cm}}
Name 1 & first & second \\ \hline\hline
value1 & \cellcolor[gray]{0.7}0.004 & 0.034 \\ 
value2 & 7721 & \cellcolor[gray]{0.7}0.14 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```